# Question about permissions on Google Cloud Dataflow

Tags: cloud, google-cloud-dataflow

I am studying  for the Data Engineer exam and, during my exercises, I have found this question:

"You are working on a sensitive project involving private user data. You have set up a project on Google Cloud Platform to house your work internally. An external consultant is going to assist with coding a complex transformation in a Google Cloud Dataflow pipeline for your project. How should you maintain users’ privacy?"

With the following possible answers:

- A. Grant the consultant the Viewer role on the project.
- B. Grant the consultant the Cloud Dataflow Developer role on the project.
- C. Create a service account and allow the consultant to log on with it.
- D. Create an anonymized sample of the data for the consultant to work within a different project.

In my opinion, answers A and C are not valid because the external developer cannot modify the pipeline. Then, I go for answer B but I do not know if the "Developer role" allows access to the data or not.

Comment: Hello Alessio. Please try to avoid asking subjective questions on Stack Overflow. Follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask questions and which [type](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) of questions to avoid asking on Stack Overflow in order to avoid questions getting flagged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to Dataflow security and permissions doc [1] and the role of Dataflow Developer [2], Dataflow Developer is that you use to run Dataflow job, but it is not enough to access any data, you need to set up properly with any roles.

Therefore this question I will go D.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions#accessing_bigquery
[2] https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/access-control#roles

Comment: Thanks for your answer but if the Developer role is not enough to access any data the correct answer should be B not D, right?

Comment: Answer D seems like without any sensitive data that still be able to code and debug. Answer B only runs the dataflow job, but without any data, you may have trouble debugging.

Comment: Can a person with dataflow developer role create jobs? I assume only dataflow admin role gives us that privilege.

Comment: You might want to check this [url](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/access-control#roles)